# Is there a way to handle discontinuities with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am running ffmpeg like this, to get a screenshot from an HLS manifest:

`ffmpeg -i 'https://example.com/myfile.ism/manifest' -vframes 1 test.jpg -y`

There are times where there are gaps in the HLS manifest. When I run that command, it fails because it can't find a frame. Is there anything I can do to make it more resilient? ie if it fails getting the time this very second, try the second before that?

When I watch the video in something like video.js, or even HLS directly in Safari, I see a frame regardless of gaps. It just jumps sometimes - I always see a frame.

How would I be able to replicate that here such that the ffmpeg command will always return a frame?